# How to read Live streaming data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I want to read live streaming data from my URL(ie.http://..) 
My URL(ie.http://..) contain numeric data and it's continuously growing.
i want to read that data in to my file(HTML5 & javascript).
      I have done with static numeric data using AJAX.
But while duing it with dynamic data(live streaming data). i am not able to get responseText().
Is it possible to take responseText() of that URL(ie.http://..) which contain live streaming data?
how i can do this?
My code for reading static data is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>    

<script type="text/javascript">
  function accessWebservice()
    {           
        var xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

 //xmlhttp.open("get","http://192.168.15.174/Streamer/StartStream.aspx?IsTestData=true",true);   
 //above URL contains live streaming numberic data that i want to read
 //But when i am using above URL i am not getting responseText (**How to get it?**)
  xmlhttp.open("get","http://localhost/StaticDemoData.txt",true);   //This contains static data
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
         {
             if (xmlhttp.status == 200 )
              {
                 var responseData=xmlhttp.responseText;
           alert(responseData);
              }
             else
             {
                 alert("Server returned: " + xmlhttp.status);
             }
         }
        }

        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
</script>
</head>
```

How to get 'xmlhttp.responseText' for live streaming numeric data?

Comment: Google AJAX Push Engine. That should get you started.

Comment: @user1037552 Can you share with us some of the coded attempts you've made, and perhaps a few more details about your request?

Comment: Also that code snipped you posted is XHTML 1.0 and nothing whatsoever to do with HTML5.

Comment: @Ian Devlin :i have changed  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> to <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: http response headers perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

If you check for `xmlhttp.readyState == 3` (XMLHttpRequest.LOADING), then accessing `xmlhttp.responseText` will give you the data that has been received from your server so far. You can then use a setInterval to constantly check `xmlhttp.responseText` for new data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script to get stream your data... but you need jquery.js file in your directory and StaticDemoData.txt you can change with other file in .php extension and get your query on the file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  userdetails();
});


function userdetails(){
     $.post('StaticDemoData.txt',function(data){
         $('.result').html(data);
       });     

       setTimeout("userdetails()",1000);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```