# XHR request stream with blobs

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, blob

is it possible to use `XMLHttpRequest` to stream data chunks as binary `blobs` into the original `blob`? (like appending to a file as data comes in from the stream) *my apologies if this a dumb or flawed question I am new to Javascript and web development in general*

Comment: If I understand right your question this may help you : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: I am confused? where in that page the description for streaming data? The data source i want to stream with HXMLHttpRequest is a live stream video file I can't wait for to finish.

Comment: I understand , try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8738238/4461056 , it's similar to your question .

Comment: wow thanks so much, i had no idea thats how it worked!